# Conceptual question on image pattern representation

Tags: image-processing, discrete-data, pattern-recognition, image-segmentation

I have a basic question regarding pattern learning, or pattern representation. Assume I have a  complex pattern of this form, could you please provide me with some research directions or concepts that I can follow to learn how to represent (mathematically describe) these forms of patterns? in general the pattern does not have a closed contour nor it can be represented with analytical objects like boxes, circles etc.

[image: binary discrete pattern]

Comment: How about performing PCA on the pattern dataset and then projecting each pattern onto PC space?

Comment: As we know, PCA is most efficient when the random variables are following Gaussian distribution, while in this case they are binary (discrete and non gaussian).

Comment: you may wanna look at kernel pca